# clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h file not found

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I followed the steps on this website:http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/

And I've installed clang 2.7 on my ubuntu,but I get the error  : **/clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h file not found.**

I use the find command to search the RecursiveASTVisitor.h but I can just find **ASTVisitor.h** file. So I think maybe I just installed the wrong version. But I don't know where to find the information that from which version clang begin to use RecursiveASTVisitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecursiveASTVisitor.h` was added to clang in version 2.8.